# Array of string expanded to path?

Tags: bash, string, array

Suppose I have the following initialization of bash array:

```
my_array=(
    "/usr/bin"
    "/usr/lib/*.so"
)
```

If I do iteration using:

```
for array_item in ${my_array[@]} 
do 
    ... 
done
```

Then the content of the `my_array` is expanded containing path to any files with .so extension in /usr/lib/ directories. but I just wanted the array contain two string which is `"/usr/bin"` and `"/usr/lib/*.so"`.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for array_item in "${my_array[@]}"
do 
    ...
done
```

or

```
for idx in $(seq ${#my_array})
do
    array_item="${my_array[$idx]}"
done
```

Comment: no, its not working, the file list still expanded.

Comment: The first one works for me in bash 3.2.48 and both in zsh 4.3.9.

Comment: oh ok, my fault I should echo using quotes for `array_item` (I use bash 4.1.7 btw)

Comment: Good to hear it. I'm on "wrong" system so I needed to test it on shell server - hence not brand new shell ;)

Comment: I think `for idx in ${!a[@]}` is preferable to using `seq` since it avoids unnecessarily using an external program and works even if the array is sparse.